# Visual Studio 2010 local testing server stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Just recently I tried to build my mvc 3 project, however the local server will not load in the browser, it just says that the web page cannot be displayed almost instantly on both IE9 and Firefox...

Strange thing is it was working fine not two weeks ago, I have tried searching google but have not come up with any solutions.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Which server are you using? The inbuilt one (cassini)? IIS? IISExpress? Other?

Comment: I am just using the default server that Visual Studio starts when I click the build button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after looking high and low I found this article [Is Your ASP .Net Development Server Not Working?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2010/06/15/is-your-asp-net-development-server-not-working.aspx). It was some changes that were made to my hosts file by a seperate installer, after modifying my hosts file as suggested in the article it once again works.

Answer (score 0):

sometime MVC project have a infected build so try these step

1. try to rebuild , clean and do  the disk clean then restart your system. maybe it's possible code work fine.

are you can show browser snapshot then i am sure what was matter with project you trying to run.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion but it is not just this one project, all my projects are now failing to build. It is quite frustrating. I think I will just try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: It actualy loads the page when I use 127.0.0.1, but it does not seem to work very well, etc slow, some pages don't load at all after redirect... Any sugestions?

Comment: don't worry you can build by other compiler such as Visual web developer or by Webmatrix.